# Function or procedure has too many arguments specified when I'm using a SqlDataSource's UpdateCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, parameters, updatecommand

I'm using a gridview with editing and updating enabled and using the `UpdateCommand` in the `SqlDataSource` to update the data. But whenever I try to update a record I get the exception

> Function or procedure has too many arguments specified

Code:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Manager_UnApprovedActivites : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
   {
        string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string Appproval =     ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["id"].DefaultValue = id.ToString();
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["approval"].DefaultValue = Appproval.ToString();
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
    }
}
```

ASP.net:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UnApprovedActivites.aspx.cs" Inherits="Manager_UnApprovedActivites" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
       </div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="AcitivityId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            Height="273px" Width="976px" AutoGenerateEditButton ="True">
          <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="AcitivityId" HeaderText="AcitivityId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AcitivityId" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActiviityName" HeaderText="ActiviityName" SortExpression="ActiviityName" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityLocation" HeaderText="ActivityLocation" SortExpression="ActivityLocation" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityStartDate" HeaderText="ActivityStartDate" SortExpression="ActivityStartDate" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDueDate" HeaderText="ActivityDueDate" SortExpression="ActivityDueDate" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDescription" HeaderText="ActivityDescription" SortExpression="ActivityDescription" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ActvityTypeId" HeaderText="ActvityTypeId" SortExpression="ActvityTypeId" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="BarchId" HeaderText="BarchId" SortExpression="BarchId" />
             <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Approval(Authority)" HeaderText="Approval(Authority)" SortExpression="Approval(Authority)" />
             <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ApprovalManager" HeaderText="ApprovalManager" SortExpression="ApprovalManager" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAdded" HeaderText="DateAdded" SortExpression="DateAdded" />
          </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WCA DatabaseConnectionString2 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Activities]" 
            UpdateCommand="ApproveActivity" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <UpdateParameters>
                   <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int64" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="approval" Type="Boolean" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1000526.aspx/1 asks to: _make sure you have the same paramList declared in <UpdateParameters> section as your SP's paramList_.

Comment: What does the `ApproveActivity` stored procedure look like? What parameters does it take?

Comment: the code for ApprvedActivity
    
    id bigint,
    approval bit
    as
    UPDATE [WCA Database].[dbo].[Activities] 
    SET ApprovalManager = approval 
    WHERE AcitivityId = id

Comment: Yes - fine - but I wanted to see **what parameters** you have defined on your stored procedure,....

Answer (score 0):

in following Line :

```
  string Appproval =     ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
```

that return CheckBox Text Not checkBox value , instead use this

```
CheckBox chb= ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Controls[0]);             
if (chb != null)
            {
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["approval"].DefaultValue =chb.Checked;
            }
```